# Android Seekbar can't remove padding/background

Tags: android, padding, seekbar

What I want to achieve is something like this, a seekbar without any top and bottom padding:
[image]

What I get is this:
[image]

I tried even setting the background to transparent and then null but the background of the seekbar becomes white, it doesn't look like in the first image, I want the seekbar to look like it's placed between the both layouts (the upper layout is darker, and the layout from the bottom is lighter as you see in both photos). I'm using the basic attributes for the seekbar in xml, thanks!

EDIT:
This is the seekBar in XML.
I don't believe that it has something to do with the root layout, because everywhere if I'm starting a new project and I'm adding a seekbar it still has that background, and if I try to set it to transparent it becomes white.

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/window_song_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor"
        android:paddingLeft="0px"
        android:paddingRight="0px" />
```

Comment: This issue is not related to the seekBar padding, Kindly show the whole xml code to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set following attributes in xml.
'android:paddingStart="0dp"
 android:paddingEnd="0dp"'

Comment: He's asking about top/bottom padding, not start/end.

Answer (score -4):

SOLVED, bad layout positioning. I was using a LinearLayout as the root element with a vertical orientation, the seekbar was at the middle of two relative layouts, I used android:background="@color/myColor" for the root layout, then setting the background to transparent to the seekbar and now I got the desired effect. And also I changed the root layout from linear layout to a relative layout. Thank you! :)